# .switchClass() acts on classes but easing does not occur

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, easing

I am trying to reveal a set of divs with a given class by using the jQuery UI switchClass() method (the class I am switching is not the one I am using to select the divs)

My main objective is that the divs should animate between states, which specifically is a height adjustment (from zero - hidden, to non-zero revealed).

The switchClass method allows you to specify the transition time, which I have done, but while the classes switch correctly, the state is delayed-instantaneous (not transitional. So after a delay equivalent to the ease time specified, the class swap happens instantly.

Here is my code:

**jQuery**

```
        function revealWarnings(){
        $('.container-warning').switchClass( 'packed', 'unpacked', 1000, 'linear' );            
    }
```

**CSS**

```
.packed{
height:0 !important;
}
.unpacked{
height:32px !important;
}
```

My jQuery UI (stated from my source file) is:

> jQuery UI - v1.11.4 - 2015-04-05

Comment: Applying CSS transitions on the classes you're switching may also give you the desired effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `!important` notation in your css rules, which overrides the inline css applied by the animation.

```
.packed {
    height:0;
}
.unpacked {
    height:32px;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4ottvad1/)

Note: If you had any specific reason to use `!important`, please share them(and recreate the issue using the above fiddle) so that we can have a look at it.

---

If you can use css3 animations then

```
.container-warning {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: height 1s;
}
.packed {
    height:0 !important;
}
.unpacked {
    height:32px !important;
}
```

then

```
$('.container-warning').removeClass('packed').addClass('unpacked');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4ottvad1/3/)

Comment: Fantastic - thanks. I was just using the !important because I wanted to make sure whereever I use those classes they'd override anything else, but I guess if they are applied inline they always will anyway. Thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 0):

make sure including jquery-ui.css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```